# Unable to crawl my new site using Google Search Console

Tags: jquery, django-rest-framework, seo, web-crawler, bots

I am developing a site with backend as **django** and frontend as **jquery**.

When calling a list/detail page url, I'll be calling an ajax method on pageload and renders data from the backend. In the backed result is serialized to json data by django and rendered back to ajax.

For eg:

```
function listFunction(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '<listing-url>',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
  })
  .done(function(response){
      // response as json
      $.each(response, function(index, value){
        $(container).append(value)
      });
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(e){
  listFunction();
});
```

In-order to check how my site is seen by google, I tested my listing page in **google search console** :

https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en

I used **Fetch and Render** option in **Fetch as Google** tab. In the result only the static contents such as page header, footer is being loaded, none of the dynamic contents loaded via ajax is displayed in the result. I have created **sitemaps** and **robots.txt** for the site.

Seo is very important for our project. How can I display my dynamic contents while using the Fetch as Google?

Please let me know if I have missed something in the coding part.

Thank you.

Comment: Just now I have also used https://tools.pingdom.com to analyse the application. Here also dynamic content is not being shown in html snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?visit_id=1-636530778960864558-2726882008&rd=1), this suggests there is an issue with your page code, as Fetch and Render does execute scripts.

The Google Search Console is capable of crawling the website, since the static content is displayed. Your issue is unrelated to robots.txt or sitemaps.

Comment: Hi JVerstry, the issue was with JS syntax I was using. I was using latest syntax such as backtick( ` ). But it was not recognized by IE browser.  I changed the JS syntax old (using babeljs) and the site rendered correctly in IE and Google Search Console. Google Search console also uses the same mechanism used by IE br